# Fingering for arpeggio in Scriabin's piano sonata no. 1

Tags: piano, fingering, arpeggios

What fingering is recommended for the righthand section here? I'd originally been using 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-4-135, but at around dotted quarter = 80-85 it's started to feel quite difficult and I've hit a bit of a wall on getting it faster, and I've been playing with using 1-2-4-1-2-4-1-2-4-5-134. The arpeggios themselves seem a bit more natural (which makes sense, I realize 1-2-3 was not in line with standard arpeggio fingerings -- I've been away from the piano for many years and wasn't really thinking) but the 4-5-134 bit is proving difficult to get clean, although I've only been practicing this fingering for a day or two.

I just want to get others' thoughts on the fingerings before I spend too much time trying to refine the 1-2-4 one only to hit a wall like I did with 1-2-3 and realize fingering wasn't my problem.

[image: Measure 2 arpeggio][image: Measure 4 arpeggio]

I have medium-sized hands, can reach a comfortable 9th and an uncomfortable white-key 10th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track.

For the arpeggio, 1-2-4 makes the most sense. It takes advantage of the space between fingers 1 and 2 and the greater space between 2-4 than 2-3.

For the final repetition within the arpeggio, however, I'd switch to 1-2-3, which is to say 1-2-3-4-135 for the end of the passage. If necessary, some very light pedal could be used to ease the "stretch" from 2-3 if a break in the sound can't be avoided fingers-only.

Comment: Great, that was the other thing I'd played with a tiny bit but I was having more trouble switching from 1-2-4 to 1-2-3 at the end than either fingering individually -- but again, I haven't spent a ton of time on these new fingerings yet, so with practice will probably be fine. My bigger problem with 1-2-3 wasn't the 2-3 stretch, it was passing the 1 under after -- to make the stretch more natural, my palm was angled inward slightly, then I had to straighten it to get the 1 there cleanly. But the last instance has no thumb pass so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @voskresenie Glad it's helpful. The key to remembering the switch from 1-2-4 to 1-2-3, in my experience, is to be aware of where you're headed. When conscious of the chord coming up at the end of the run, I find it easier to make the fingering adjustment. In fact, as a practice technique, try placing the chord early: in other words, practice 1-2-4, 1-2-4, 1-2-135. That will help ensure your entire hand is in the right place at the right time.

Comment: Ahh, that's an interesting idea -- you're saying, practice skipping the last F-G and go straight to the chord? I hadn't thought of that but I think that's a good idea. The problems I've had with hitting the chord cleanly at faster tempos have mostly been from focusing on the two notes leading up to it and then my thumb isn't over the Ab (hovering too close to edge of keyboard) when it needs to be and I kinda frantically smash it over. That exercise will I think be helpful in addressing that (as well as the 1-2-4 to 1-2-3 switch).

Comment: @voskresenie Perfect. You understand both the technique and the purpose. It's a good tool in general. I frequently will play (parts of) a passage as a block chord in order to determine the best hand position.

Comment: Superb recommendations, thank you. Will practice this way for a few days and reply again with how it goes!

Comment: @voskresenie Please do post a follow-up. I'd love to hear how it works (or doesn't) for you.